# Generation of JAXB based WebService Client(Stub) from WSDL

Tags: wsdl, jaxb, webservice-client

We have a requirement where we need to develop a webservice client based upon JAXB. 
We have only the **WSDL url** with us. Is there any such tool exist which can do this for us ?

As of now we are thinking of **xjc** tool, but that takes a **xsd** file as input whereas we have the **WSDL** file with us to generate the Stubs.

Please advise.

Regards
S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) which uses JAXB by default.

Using [CXF generated Client](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/how-do-i-develop-a-client.html) you can have what you need (a client) using only WSDL.

Just use:

```
wsdl2java -d <output-directory> -client <wsdlurl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old, but if anybody else stumbles about it:

A WSDL contains the schema for the domain objects in between the `<types>`-Tag.

The default tool xjc can parse wsdl with the -wsdl command line option.